# Timeout error, getting images from urls - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-3.4

I am trying to save jpegs to a file from a list of urls. This code times out frequently and randomly. It has saved up to 113 jpegs, there are many more than that, and sometimes only saves 10 before timing out. Is there a way to put a wait in so the timeout doesn't occur? I have tried sleep in the commented section with no luck. Thanks for the feedback!

Heres the timeout error message:

[image]

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
import codecs
from urllib import request
import time    
import csv

class File:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

file = File("1")

with open("file.csv", encoding = "utf8") as f1:
    file.data = list(csv.reader(f1, skipinitialspace = True))

for i in file.data[1:]:
 if len(i[27]) != 0:
     #i[14] creates a unique jpeg file name in the dir
     image = open('C:\\aPath'+i[14]+'.JPG', 'wb')
     path = 'aPath' + i[14] + '.JPG'

     #time.sleep(2)  Tried sleep here, didn't work

     #i[27] is a working jpeg url
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(i[27], path)

     image.close()
print('done!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to prevent the exception. You need to catch the exception and retry.

```
...

for i in file.data[1:]:
    if not i[27]:
        continue
    path = 'aPath' + i[14] + '.JPG'
    while True:  # retry loop
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(i[27], path)
            break  # On success, stop retry.
        except TimeoutError:
            print('timeout, retry in 1 second.')
            time.sleep(1)
```

BTW, you don't need to open file if you use `urllib.request.urlretrieve`.

Comment: Great info thanks. Is there a way to retry after the request takes longer than a second rather than waiting for the timeout error?